# addition of two results of crc 8 function

Tags: c, embedded, crc, crc8

I am using this code from this question:
[CRC8 Embedded Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482233/crc8-embedded-implementation)

this code is based on this site:

http://www.ghsi.de/pages/subpages/Online%20CRC%20Calculation/index.php?Polynom=100110001&Message=AA79

I know that the value of 0xAA79 is 0x61, and I'm also getting that result.

my question is how exactly do how I add two results of two crc-8 calculation. for instance if I would like to get the crc-8 result of "0xAA79AA79", then the above website gives me the result of 0xc0, but when I'm just adding the result of 0xAA79 twice I get 0xc2.
what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: CRC is not a simple arithmetic sum, is more a special kind of modulo calculation (remainder of division) on the data block seen as a (very) wide number. You cannot simply add CRCs of two data blocks to obtain the CRC of the concatenation of the blocks. -- You might want to read [this text](https://archive.org/stream/PainlessCRC/crc_v3.txt).

Comment: so what can I do?

Comment: Simple solution? Use both blocks as a single "block", and calculate the checksum of that.

Comment: Running the code in your first link produces output saying the CRC of input 0xAA79 is 0xAB. But your post says “I know that the value of 0xAA79 is 0x61, and I'm also getting that result.”

Comment: Your code in `crc8` initializes `crc` to zeros. To continue the CRC calculation of XY from where Y starts, simply initialize `crc` to the CRC of X instead of to zero.

Comment: There's many different CRC8 algorithms. Different polynomials, different initialization values, some doing bitwise XOR on the result etc etc. Here's a decent tutorial: https://zlib.net/crc_v3.txt

Comment: Eric Postpischil - look there for fixing that to get the correct output of 0x61.

Comment: Edit the question to contain a [mre] directly in the post, specifically a complete program that produces output matching what the post says it does.

Answer (score 2):

A CRC is not a checksum. You cannot add two CRCs arithmetically and expect that to be related in any way to the CRC of the combined sequence.

It *is* possible however to combine CRCs. [crcany](https://github.com/madler/crcany) will generate code, for any CRC definition, that does exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

Using binary math (+ means xor, % means modulo, no carries on multiplies or borrows on divide), the CRC is really calculating:

```
aa79aa7900%131        = c0
```

This can be split up into two parts, and added (xor)

```
aa79000000%131        = a1
    aa7900%131        = 61
    a1+61             = c0
```

The operations can be split up into components modulo 131

```
1000000%131           = 46 
100%31                = 31
(aa79*46)%131         = a1
(aa79*31)%131         = 61
    a1+61             = c0
```